# How to change size of CKEditor from javascript

Tags: api, ckeditor, javascript

I'm using CKEditor 3.2, trying to change the width and height of the ckeditor from javascript, i have used several methods, all unsuccesful:

```
// doesnt work 1:
CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.width = 500;

// doesnt work 2:
CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.width = 500;
CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.updateElement();

// doesnt work 3:
CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.config.width = 500;

// doesnt work 4:
CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.config.width = 500;
CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.updateElement();
```

---

Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.resize(500, 400)`